# Django not parsing form from POST request

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse an HTML form (created by Django) into a form object. The issue is that when submitting the form, I get the error `'PersonForm' object has no attribute 'name'`. I've tried using `request.POST["name"]` instead, but that didn't work either. Here's what happens when I print `form`: `<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="wow" maxlength="14" required id="id_name"></td></tr>`

This is my `models.py`:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True)
```

`forms.py`:

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from findapp.models import Person

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ["name"]
```

`views.py`:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PersonForm()
        return render(request, "findapp/person.html", {"form": form})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        print(form.name)
```

`person.html`:

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.name }}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it wrong in `views.py`.

it should be like this :

```
def index(request):
    form = PersonForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            # person = form.save(commit=False)
            print(form.cleaned_data['name'])
            # person.save()
            return HttpResponse('Ok')
    return render(request, "findapp/person.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: `person.name` is still blank :/

Comment: try changing {{form.name}} to {{form}}

Comment: same thing. are you sure that i dont need request.post?

Comment: 'PersonForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: comment out person = form.save(commit =False)

Comment: You are not triggering the cleaning and validation of the form, this is made by calling the is_valid() . check my updated answer

Comment: That works. So I should be using cleaned_data instead of attirbutes?

Comment: you have to use cleaned data to get form data in your views